# Whats the best way to get MySQL data into Date Related Groupings without crushing our db?

Tags: mysql, reporting

I have a few tables related to an app of ours in a database that needs to be lumped into buckets to help compare one source from another.

Example, we have an app install table with a source, and a timestamp
Then we have an uninstall table with a app id.

We need to be able to basically get data into a grouping of "0-7";"7-14";"15-30";"30-60" days of age.

Then select from there the amount of ininstalls that happen in similar fashion. First week, second week, second half of month, second month.

Its not so bad if we only have 50-100k installs, however when we throw in app activity in the mix, to see if that bucket did a certain action, our actions table is in themillions, and the world ends.

Is there a way we can do this with MySQL, or is it just not practical?

It almost seems easier to setup a server side script to process each row individually into a rollup table.

Install

```
| App ID       | Timestamp           | Source
--------------------------------------------------------
| foo-1        | 2015-11-23 03:49:12 | Google
| foo-2        | 2015-12-23 03:49:12 | Facebook
| foo-3        | 2015-12-31 01:10:01 | Google
```

Purchase:

```
| App ID       | Timestamp           | Amount
--------------------------------------------------------
| foo-1        | 2015-11-26 05:49:12 | $10.00
| foo-1        | 2015-12-27 03:49:12 | $5.00
```

Uninstall:

```
| App ID       | Timestamp           
--------------------------------------------------------
| foo-2        | 2015-12-15 05:49:12
```

Report: (FP = First Purchase, U = Uninstall)

```
| Source    | Total Installs | FP 0-14d | FP in 15-30 | FP in 30-60 | U in 0-14d | U in 15-30
Google      |      2         |    1     |       -     |    -        |     -      |    -
Facebook    |       1        |    -     |       -     |    -        |     1      |    -
```

Comment: Please add sample data and desired results to your question.

Comment: Aggregate operations on "millions of rows" should be no sweat, provided you have the right indexes set up.

Comment: Thank you - sample data added. I realized when adding sample data, it will be extremely hard to make these into "Age buckets" of install, and then group it by source and maintain usable data.

Comment: @Dai if we use any Mysql SUM or other math functions - it seems to crash every time. Were running a m4.2xl RDS box @ aws. So - for instance, if I try to calculate an Average of earnings per bucket, or a SUM of revenue, etc. 

CPU Spikes. The only thing I do not think we have indexed are revenue columns, but do rev columns need to be indexed to perform math when the join is on the APP UID?

Comment: @Nick What do you mean by "it seems to crash" - do you mean the process just seems to lock-up? It shouldn't be actually crashing (i.e. process terminated).

Comment: @Dai correct - CPU spikes to 100% until the process is killed. The web sockets for various reporting tools tim out before it ever completes (perisscope or phpmyadmin), but the query remains running untill killed and the server is all but unresponsive while its processing.

Comment: @Nick Use a database profiling tool and the `EXPLAIN` command to see if the lack of any indexes is causing it to slow down.

Comment: You might want to consider using mysql partitions. Since all you need is the last x days, you can also setup some cron jobs to populate some summary tables. I've dealt with this before and with proper indexing and optimized queries, a summary some some million records should not take more than a few minutes.

Comment: @AlexTartan - out of curiosity, did you update each summarizing row? And how did you handle daily processing? Ie, lastupdated field?

Comment: @Dai thanks for advice. I will play around with it :)

Comment: Update - Explain is basically complaining about the timestamps. None have indexes, however, these tables current indexes are appx 50% of the total table size.

I dont want to add them and wind up creating a bottleneck on insert as we scale. Our DB Connections climb to 70+ during peak times with only 50k users. So i think instead of putting indexes on Timestamps, it would be better to have Cron rollups?

Or - is adding indexes to timestamps really not going to slow down things that much more? Every stack post says "slight" but no one ballparks it to the nearest decimal

Comment: @Nick Index insertion is relatively cheap, however no-one can tell you what the real cost will be. You will need to profile your own code to find out.